# UIWebView verticalAlign = 'middle' does not work

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

i want to let the content of `UIWebView` to align center and middle, i use this :

```
 NSString *bodyStyle = @"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.verticalAlign = 'middle';";

[imageAttDetailsWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:bodyStyle];
```

but it does not work ,please help me! thank you !

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not depends on UIWebView but on how your code is built.

What do you exactly put in your body?

You don't necessarily need to set verticalAlign to middle, it will not work as you wrote it. Even on a normal webpage.

However, you could set it margin-top: ( 50% - ( size of your element / 2 )) of your inside elements. Say you have

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="margin-top: ( 50% - ( size of your element / 2 ))">
        My stuff here
    </div>
</body>
```

Obviously you need to have a logic to make this rule work: ( 50% - ( size of your element / 2 ))
As it is not CSS-valid. ( You could however use libraries like LESS or SASS to make it more powerful though )

Comment: thanks very much! but how can i get the size of the element,please help,thanks very much!

Comment: i use the mehtod "loadRequest" of the uiwebview to load a image.

Comment: What exactly is inside your page? Have you tried margin-top:auto; and margin-bottom;auto; ? Also, if you're unable to know content "before", then load and use jQuery to update the code. You can set jQuery("document").ready( function() { jQuery("#wrapper").css("margin-top", ( jQuery("window").innerHeight / 2 ) - ( jQuery("#wrapper").innerHeight/2 ) ) });